# How can I define, in the C programming language, a FIRST macro that let's me declare scoped variables?

Tags: c, variables, macros, scope

I have the following macros

```
#define FIRST(first) \
 switch(first, 0) default:

#define LAST(last) \
 switch(0) for(;0;last) default:

#define BRACKET(first, last) \
 switch(first, 0) for(;0;last) default:
```

And they are used like so.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// ... Macros are defined here

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int x;

    FIRST(x = 4)
    {
        printf("%i\n", x);
    }

    LAST(++x)
    {
        printf("%i\n", x);
    }

    printf("%i\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

BRACKET is simply a combination of FIRST and LAST. The FIRST macro, (and the BRACKET macro), isn't good enough though. I'd like to be able to write the following code where y is scoped to the curly braces.

```
    FIRST(int y = 0)
    {
        printf("%i\n", y);
    }
```

How can I write a FIRST macro, in the C programming language that lets me declare a variable scoped within the curly braces?

Some corner cases are:

I want the following code snippet allowed

```
FIRST(int x = 0)
 printf("%i\n", x);
```

I want the folllowing code snippet disallowed

```
FIRST(int x = 0)
 printf("%i\n", x);

++x;
printf("%i\n", x);
```

P.S. I'm surprised that "switch(0) for(;0;last) default:" is accepted by the compiler, is this really legal C code?

Comment: Please, please, don't write macros like this (unless it's just an exercise)...

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  The `switch(first, 0)` in the expansion of `FIRST` probably doesn't do what you expect or think.  The `switch (0) for(...)` probably doesn't do what you think, either.  And there is no point in obscuring the language syntax with syntactically more appropriate variations of what you seem to be trying.

Comment: Yes, the `switch (0) for (;0;last) default:` notation is valid, but the loop semantics are excruciatingly non-obvious. The `switch (0)` jumps to the default label (bypassing the loop controls), executes the loop body, does the post-loop `last` in the `for` loop control, and then tests the loop condition `0` and finds it is false so that the loop exits. The compiler will likely optimize away quite a lot of that mess. But those coming after you shouldn't be obliged to work out that you could simply write: `printf("%d\n", x); ++x;` to achieve the result of `LAST(++x) { printf("%d\n", x); }`.

Comment: What in the world are you trying to accomplish with this needlessly complicated roundabout way of setting variables?

Answer (score 1):

To obtain scoped variables in the way you want is easy if you have a compiler that is at least complying to C99. (otherwise don't do it, or get yourself a modern compiler).

A prefix to a block or statement like `FIRST(int y = 0)` can be realized by something like

```
for (int t = 0; t < 1; ++t)
  for(int y = 0; t < 1; ++t)
```

that is you define an auxiliary variable that controls the loop to be executed exactly once. Modern compilers easily optimize the noise that comes with this and go to the essential.

With some care you can pack that into a macro, where you should take care that the name also captures what is going on and that you don't hurt the eyes of your fellow programmers. In particular put a big warning label somewhere that such things change the semantic of `break` and `continue` statements to something quite surprising for the unaware reader.

I have written up more on [scope bound resource management with `for`-scopes](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/08/14/scope-bound-resource-management-with-for-scopes/).

Comment: I wanted to try that approach, but I didn't like the idea of declaring  a variable inside a macro. Still, it might be saner then my way.